# Lg front load washer not doing high speed spin (wm2650hwa)

Tags: repair, washer

My washer will go through all cycles then last 7 min does not do high speed cycle.  I had repair man come he said was control panel.  I replaced control panel, pump and hall sensor.  I did a reset. Then ran the machine twice empty and it worked perfect. Went through all cycles and did the high speed spin perfect.  I then put a small load in it and it went through the cycles until 7 min to go tries to go in to high then just goes to 1 min and shuts off.  Clothes are very wet.  Flashed LE code.  First time that happened.  With the parts I have replaced I am wondering if it is the stator.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Based on you description the control board is doing its job/functions.

It is possible the pump not doing its job.

It can not spin at high speed until water is pumped out, so check for water level.

I could be also the belt connecting the motor and the drum (slipping). If the belt is to loose, adjust the tension. The belt might be also worn out and needs replacement.